# Запуск функции после загрузки всех данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Есть несколько функций, каждая из которой делает Ajax запрос. Потом надо запустить функцию, которая будет работать с загруженными данными. Вот только как мне запустить эту функцию тогда, когда все данные уже загрузятся?

Таймер ставить - "костыльное" решение. Как вариант, в возвращаемом значении Ajax запроса функции `a1` я запускаю функцию `a2` и так далее много раз. В результате чего тоже запутываюсь - что куда идёт.

Есть ли нормальный вариант запуска функции тогда, когда все необходимые данные уже будут загружены? На AngularJS / jQuery или просто на JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, Angular использует `$q` и можно использовать `$q.all` . [Официальное описание](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

И небольшой пример:

```
function query(url){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var result = $http.get(url)
     .then(function(){          
       deferred.resolve(result);
     });         

   return deferred.promise;
}

$q
 .all([query('/users.php'),query('/books.php')])
 .then(function(data){
   console.log(data); 
 }) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1, a2) {
...
});
```